# Split from number with possible decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to split a string from where a number is encountered. The problem is the number can sometimes have decimals in it.

I tried this without any luck:

```
str = "hello there can sometimes be decimals like 1.5 in here"
var parts = str.split(/\d*\.?\d*/);
```

The intended result would be an array with everything before the number in first position, then the number, then the rest of the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not much of an issue in this case, but try to avoid regex like `x*x*`. It would be better to not just make the comma optional, but the digits after the comma as well: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`.

Comment: `/^([^\d]*?)(\d+|\.\d+|\d+\.\d+)([^\d]*?)$/` -> `["hello there can sometimes be decimals like 1.5 in here", "hello there can sometimes be decimals like ", "1.5", " in here"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a one-liner for this, but something like this should work.

First the regex needs to be fixed to use `+` instead of `*` by the first `\d`, to make sure it matches the first part:

```
/\d+\.?\d*/
```

Then, we need to extract the number, split, and add it into the array:

```
str = "hello there can sometimes be decimals like 1.5 in here"
var num = str.match(/\d+\.?\d*/);
var parts = str.split(/\d+\.?\d*/);
parts.splice(1,0,num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'hello there can sometimes be decimals like 1.5 in here';
var firstDigit = str.indexOf(str.match(/\d/))-1 ;

function splitValue(value, index) {
var parts =[value.substring(0, index),value.substring(index)] ;  
   return parts;
}
```